# Image segmentation for the fingerprint image

Tags: java, image, algorithm, image-processing, fingerprint

I am working on image processing for the fingerprint image.In that i want to do image segmentation.Is there any algorithm for image segmentation for the fingerprint image in java?

Input Image  & Segmented Image:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is "the fingerprint image" ? Is there any particular image you are referring to? Image segmentation can be done in Java. Try using javaCV or implement a custom watershed algorithm. But what have you tried till now?

Comment: I have the fingerprint image captured from device.And have not started for the image segmentation.

Comment: Rachana, please, be more clear about what you want to do. How is this image? Would you mind to post a sample? What do you want to segmentate? Separate the fingerprint from other elements in the image? Extract fingerprint features?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do fingerprint recognition from an image, there are several steps for the entire process. First of all you have to do some pre-processing steps which can be an adaptive thresholding. Then you can look into morphological processes like opening and closing. After each step carefully observe the output and then think upon what next to use.
Lastly you would need pattern recognition techniques for which you can use libraries which implement them using neural networks ex : http://www.learnartificialneuralnetworks.com/art.html